# Convert Apache VirtualHost to nginx Server Block for Dynamic Subdomains

Tags: apache, dynamic, nginx, vhosts

I have a web app running on Apache where the virtual hosts file is configured to route requests to subdomains to specific folders.  Rather than having to modify the host file every time a subdomain is created, this allows me to dynamically route URLs to the relevant folder (with a catchall if the folder doesn't exist) -

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName localhost.com
    ServerAlias *.localhost.com
    VirtualDocumentRoot "/var/www/clients/%1"
    ErrorLog "logs\errors.log"
    <directory "/var/www/clients/%1">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from all
    </directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I am trying to convert the above to nginx but cannot find the right logic to extract the subdomain from the URL and then set the `root` variable in the config file.

Can anyone help me to write the `server {}` block for nginx, together with a catch-all block if the `root` path doesn't exist?

Comment: `server {
  server_name ~^(.*)\.localhost\.com$ ;
  root var/www/clients/$1;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a named regex capture in the server_name that you can refer to later.

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name ~^(?<subdir>.*)\.localhost\.com$ ;

    set $rootdir "/var/www/clients";
    if ( -d "/var/www/clients/${subdir}" ) { set $rootdir "/var/www/clients/${subdir}"; }
    root $rootdir;
}
```

What your are doing is setting your default root directory to a variable `$rootdir` and then overwriting it if the subdirectory set by `$subdir` exists.

Comment: Many thanks for this.  Unfortunately it is not working as expected.  under the `/var/www/clients` directory I have a directory `client1` with an index.html.  I also have an index.html under the catch-all directory.  If I navigate to `http://client1.localhost.com` nginx is returning the catch-all page (i.e. going directly to `$rootdir` instead of `$rootdir/client1`.

Comment: I have switched the order of setting the default. It should work now.

Comment: I have changed the `server` block  to `server {
 listen 8080;
 server_name *.localhost.com;
 if ( -d "/var/ww/clients/$subdir" ) { set $rootdir "/var/www/clients/$subdir"; }
 if ( $rootdir == "" ) { set $rootdir '/var/www/clients'; }
 root $rootdir;
}
` but when I try to restart nginx with `sudo service nginx restart` it fails.

Comment: Thanks. I went ahead and tested and found the error. I also simplified by taking from your example of what you tried.